# Proper save format for preview for editable pictures

Tags: preview, image-editing

Suppose you edit a picture in Preview and added new elements such as text. In what format should you save the file if you want to resume editing the added elements, like changing the font of the text for example?

Comment: Good question. Potential duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/233691/12509

Answer (score 1):

I dont think such a portable editable document can be made in preview. It will export in these formats.

> [image]

I don't know about HEIC and OpenEXR, but none of the others would allow such modifications AFAIK, if done from Preview.